# Polymorphism with generics on the repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, design-patterns, repository

I have a problem using the Repository pattern in C# especially when I try to implement a Façade pattern too. My concept follows:

When I first started the generic repository, I began with one which has all the CRUD operations in a single file (and their related interfaces in a separate single file). But because of the SOLID principles and in particular the ISP principle, I decided to segregate all the interfaces into separate files, and do likewise with the classes.

So for example instead of having IGenericRepo with the various Create, Read ... methods in one file, and the corresponding GenericRepo in another. I segregated them all out having a base repo to do anything common. So I ended up with an ICreateRepo, an IReadOneRepo, an IReadManyRepo...etc.

As time passed, my project needs grew, and I found myself needing multiple "Read" operations:

- Read a single record with the given id,

> ```
>      public T Read(int id)
> ```

- Read a single record which could potentially have compound primaries having to pass in multiple values. Works like the EF Find Method...i.e.

> ```
>      public T Read(params object[] keyValues)
> ```

- Return the first record based on a search on any field...like the EF Where Method, which had parameter like...

> ```
>      public T Read(Expression<Func<T>,bool>> predicate)
> ```

This was fine until I came across a situation where I needed to read multiple records and return a list of all records that matched the criteria. Essentially the read operation had the same method signature as the last one mentioned, differing only in its return type. One returned a single entity, the other returned a list of matching entities.

```
   public IQueryable<T> Read(Expression<Func<T>,bool>> predicate)
```

While separated out into their own classes there was no issue. However I found in my controllers (I use MVC) that I had long lists of repositories about 6 or 9 and I wanted to simplify this to one like what I had for the single generic. So I turned to the Façade pattern.

Now when I bring together the read functionalities, I will have a problem with polymorphic behaviour because the signatures are the same.

```
    //ReadOne 1
    public T Read(int id)
    { }
    //ReadOne 2
    public T Read(params object[] keyValues)
    { }
    //ReadOne 3 *** Signature same as search except for return type.
    public T Read(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        //SingleOrDefault used purposefully instead of FirstOrDefault to cause exception if
        //there is more than one instance that meets the predicate.
        return dbSet.Where(predicate).SingleOrDefault<TEntity>();
    }

    //Search
    public IQueryable<T> Read(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return dbSet.Where(predicate);
    }

    //ReadAll
    public IQueryable<T> Read()
    { }
```

As mentioned... When separated into separate files, these worked fine as they were explicitly called as needed. But I want to use the Façade pattern to simplify the code.

The problem I am having of course is that there is no polymorphism based on return type. I understand the and fully appreciate reasons for this.

I was thinking of adding an optional bool parameter to the end of the search. But it doesn't feel right for some reason. Something like...

```
    //Search
    public IQueryable<T> Read(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, bool returnOne = false)
    { }
```

So my question is, has anyone got ideas on how to get around this limitation?

Comment: Since the caller needs to know the difference between something that returns a `T` and something that returns an `IQueryable<T>` anyway, it seems to me that you should simply name the methods differently. E.g. `Read()` and `ReadQueryable()` or something like that. If that's not possible, you should significantly simplify your question so that it states your question more precisely. I doubt you really need to even mention design patterns, never mind elaborate on your use of them, to express the _specific_ question you have. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Whats the point of polymorphism if your going to rename every method. SOLID principles mentioned state DIP as another principle. Effectively meaning I should not be letting my calling classes be tightly coupled. What you suggest, renaming methods, would go against this. As regard to your comment on design patterns, they are paramount to this question. So is there something in the question guidelines against mentioning them...I'm here 3 years, I never seen anything in the how-to-ask link that says don't mention design patterns. However, thanks for your comment.

Comment: If you have a specific suggestion on how to improve the question I would be happy to make required edits. I looked at your link and feel the question is clear. So your contempt for it is confusing. However, I do use design patterns a lot and I feel they are relevant to the question and this is why they are so prevalent throughout. Apologies if your lack of design pattern understanding limit your ability to answer. If I can improve the question to aid your understanding and encourage an answer, please advise. I very much appreciate that you have taken the time to explain the close and down vote

Comment: I think you might want to explain why you thought that seggregating the repository into separate interfaces is good idea in your opionion, and what you think it is that you gain from this? And secondly, I completely agree that you can solve the problem by renaming, besides, if someone reads the code, he has no idea what Read(10) means. Try ReadById(10), or something similiar. That said, I don't understand your comment about "what's the point of polymorphism if you're going to rename every method"? Might want to clarify that too.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa - Thanks for the feedback. With regard to the reason for separation this was explained in the second paragraph re Interface Segregation Principle (ISP) taken from one of the 5 SOLID principles. The other reason is explained in my next comment.

Comment: Also..."If someone reads...Read(10) means". I have no idea what read(10) means either. But I do know what Read(Id) means given that id is passed from a query string or some other such place, so renaming every read to ReadById(studentId), ReadByCompoundPK(studentId, courseId), ReadByFirstMatch(id ==> student.studentId == studentId && student.age == age). Effectively they all read based on something passed in and return a single record. So why NOT use polymorphism. Isnt this the prime reason for it?

Comment: One of the requirements of this site is that people asking questions do their research. I have shown that I have researched this significantly given that the comments so far have been me tutoring others on the basic SOLID and OOP principles. So I respectfully request that only readers who have relevant knowledge answer the question. If it's fair to expect me to do research before asking, answers should come from those that know the areas prior to answering. It's neither a requirement, and I simply cant,  give basic tutorials on very simple OOP patterns and principles to every commenter.

Comment: It seems like your interpretation of this "design pattern" is going to be confusing to other developers.  A developer looking at the method named "Read" should be expecting similar actions from all of the Read methods.  Your comments clearly indicate that 2 of your Read methods are not like the others.  I don't see why you can't name the first three "Read" and the last two "Search" (ReadAll can be like a search with no limits).

Comment: @Grax - +1 - I guess when you look at it from that perspective it makes more sense. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried the trick you described of adding a useless parameter to change the signature but like you said, it feels so dirty that I try to avoid it.

Comment: @Grax - I done a small edit to the code to show the reason why I am reluctant to rename it from read to search. Effectively ReadOne 3 and Search are the same code, just the first is purposefully limited. Given they are the same effective implementations and signatures with only one minor difference, this is what was causing my reluctance to rename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rename the single-entity returning `Read` to `ReadSingle`, to make it clear that, even though it takes a predicate as a parameter, it only returns a single entity. I'd try renaming *first*.

If you'd prefer another option, you could differentiate the method signatures in their parameters. You can create a predicate-wrapper type for the single-returning oddball case:

```
public class ExpressionToFindSingle<T> {
  private Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate;
  public ExpressionToFindSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {
    this.predicate = predicate;
  }
  public static implicit operator Expression<Func<T, bool>>(ExpressionToFindSingle<T> wrapper) {
    return wrapper.predicate;
  }
}
```

Given the conversion operator, you can use the wrapper as its predicate directly. To make things simpler for callers, you can also extend `Expression<..>` to more easily create this wrapper:

```
public static class Predicates {
  public static ExpressionToFindSingle<T> ForSingle<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {
    return new ExpressionToFindSingle<T>(predicate);
  }
}
```

Then, your class can have these methods (showing only their signatures):

```
T Read(ExpressionToFindSingle<T> predicate);

IQueryable<T> Read(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
```

Comment: Had to read it twice to fully understand what was going on. However the difficulty can be tucked away somewhere. So I like it a lot. I believe it will lead to clearer code and is definitely the best solution I have seen so far. The main thing I was looking for was a way to allow me to keep the names (use polymorphism), and differentiate based on the signature in a way that was very obvious. This solution provides that. The return type is sufficient to let consumers know what they'll get back (single / many). So good work and thanks for your answer.

Comment: I do have a question however. Its mostly down to naming I think. The name SinglePredicateExpression vs MultiPredicateExpression is a bit confusing for me. The issue I have with my current system is the polymorphic signatures are the same, only the return type is different in ReadOne 3 vs Search. However, if I disable either one, I can pass in either single or multiple predicates and get the desired result every time. The naming of the predicates in this way suggests the methods which use them are limited for example to a single predicate in the case of readOne 3. This should not be the case.

Comment: There are situations where I would need to pass in multiple predicates to ReadOne 3, returning the first result as explained. Vice versa on the search. So perhaps I have missed something? It makes sense to me that just because a method returns only a single record, does not mean it will have only a single input. Its also a reasonable assumption to say that it may need to search on multiple fields to find that single record. Vice versa for search. Returning multiple records is usually expected even if you only insert a single predicate, i.e. all the invoices belonging to customer with id of 5.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers: You're absolutely right, the naming is not really good. To really convey the message, they should be named something like `ExpressionThatShouldYieldOneResult` and `ExpressionPossiblyYieldingManyResults`, but I'm sure you can find even better names (or, as a matter of fact, actually good ones). I can update the answer once we find better names.

Comment: Also, let me reiterate that I'd still prefer the renaming option. The polymorphism you're thinking about (I believe, given your language of choice) is the sub-typing kind, but with the same names and different parameters what you have is simply method overloading (aka [ad hoc polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism)).

Comment: If its only names that were the issue we would have an accepted answer for sure. But I'm not understanding how the input connects directly with the output. As explained in my 3rd comment. The fact that ReadOne 3 returns only one result doesn't mean it should take only a single predicate. Vice versa with search, as I could pass only a customer id into an invoices table to find all invoices for that customer. So the bigger issue is, how does the wrapping / restriction of the predicate map to the result set or am I drawing a line where none exists because of not fully understanding?

Comment: The wrapping of the predicate is merely to allow two overloads that differ in their return value (a workaround), and could be used to convey how differently the methods operate (together with the return value). But still, I think renaming the methods would better convey that message.

Comment: So if I understand, then instead of focusing on the predicate, it should focus on the return? So maybe instead of naming it SinglePredicateExpression we could consider SingularReturn. Likewise for multi. However, this is with the assumption that we can still pass in multiple predicate expressions to a SinglePredicateExpression / SingularReturn. Otherwise it's still misleading. My concern is that I want to be able to do something like xyz.Read(x => x.customerID == custId && x.invoiceID = invId) or its equivalent into the singular predicate expression. Is this possible?

Comment: Again I apologise if I am not fully understanding and appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Sure it's possible, it's just that the naming is confusing. Again, think about what's the intent of the method. They both take predicates (and both can have multiple conditions), but they return different cardinalities. The first returns ONE, so its predicate could be called `PredicateThatShouldYieldOnlyOne`; the second, `PredicateThatCanPossiblyYieldMany`. Now, these names are too unwieldy, so we need to find better ones.

Comment: For the ONE, it could be `PredicateToFindSingle`, and for the MULTI, simply `Predicate` (since it already implies that it could filter in many results, I think). What do you think?

Comment: You could also create a wrapper only for the single case, since that's the oddball case.

Comment: ok. As its down to naming, lets pretend that in the example, ReadOne 1 Doesn't exist. Now if we took ReadOne 3 and Search and simply replaced the expression<func> with an int id. It would be clear to the caller, that passing an id to the ReadOne 3, will return singular, passing the same id to the search will possibly return multiple. This can be deduced clearly from the return type. So sticking with the example of int id for simplicity and clarity I'll continue in the next comment...

Comment: continued...If this was a simple int id. We would not likely wrap the int and name one IntThatReturnsOne, and IntThatReturnsMany. I guess what I am asking is, is the fact that one or many returned a concern of the parameter especially given they are both the same. If not then we are left with 2 wrappers called IntThat and are back to where we started. To which the best solution is given polymorphism doesn't work on return types, its best to rename the search method to search. Am I understanding your example correctly with regard to the wrapping of the ints?

Comment: Yes, it makes perfect sense. As I mentioned, it's a workaround, meant to allow us to define two methods that only fundamentally differ on their return types. And yes, renaming is the _preferred_ solution. I will simplify my answer, and then you can think about it a little more.

Comment: While I am grateful that you put a lot of effort into this, I feel it would be bad form to accept solely on that basis as that is not what SO is about. However, I will accept the answer on the basis that all along Grax suggested the best solution was to rename and he gave good reasons for this which were more solid than anyone else's (yours excepted). Also given that you suggested from the start a rename. Then went into a lot of additional detail only to eventually return full circle and mutually agree that renaming is the best solution. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I just have a quick query...would it be possible to edit the code so not to use implicit operator or extension methods or static. Not necessary but would be nice to see. Or at least add a note as to why they are used.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers: It's already stated why they're used, but I'll try to clarify further later on.

Answer (score 0):

I would return only IQueryable. Why even have the case where only one entity is returned? What if the IQueryable only has one record? I am not seeing the need I guess..

Same thing with your parameter.. why do you need explicit cases for single vs array? Just have the array.

The returnOne flag makes no sense at all to me either. Look at it this way... would you ever have a returnTwo? returnThree? No.. because at that point the design is flawed. Also I agree with the other comment that this does not really have to reference patterns, really this is a best practice issue imho.

Comment: The issue I have with your logic is...why return a queryable or array or list when you know only a single item is always required (as in the case of reading a single record by PK). This only confuses consumers and is definitely against any best practice I know. If your only returning a single item. No matter how you internally filter it down to a single item, its definitely bad voodoo to return a collection of a single item. This is not my opinion, but industry wide best practice. However, thank you for putting your idea in an answer format instead of a comment. Also thank you for your time.

Comment: However I do agree that it should not be necessary to add a special parameter for ReturnOne etc. This is also against best practice and I also agree for the same reasons you specified. So far the best solution I can see is Grax comment on renaming.

Comment: At most you really only ever need two calls in this case. "GetEntity" and "GetEntities". The single return value is just a nice-to-have. Its not "bad voodoo" to return a collection with only one item. Collections have only one item all the time. But if you really want (need?) the functionality for a single return type then at most you would have 2 as stated earlier. Also simple design is what makes an api not confusing, any developer using this code will know what to do with it. Thats the point. Having all these special cases you are actually complicating what doesn't need to be complicated.

Comment: Something like this,  public IQueryable<T> Read(Expression<Func<T>,bool>> predicate), is probably all you need.

Comment: There are various ways to get a single item. 3 of which shown in my code and all commonly used. Its improbable in any sizeable system that you will get a single item from a system that contains compound primary keys, by searching on only one of those keys. What you are proposing will lead to every consumer of your class having to check and filter the returned items to ensure they are correct. This is unmaintainable. Given the choice between 3 centralised places, and 50+ decentralised filters and what not...I'd cant agree the generic polymorphic approach is complicating things.

Comment: What you suggest is to always return an IQueryable, and then let the consumer check for null, 0, 1 or more and then filter the return as needed. Lets pretend I agreed, what happens when you have 50, 100, 1000 consumers (classes) calling this, doing this check for nulls, 0's and 1+ just to get a single record. As I said, unmaintainable.

Comment: So your id and keys are not actually ids and keys... thats even a bigger problem imho.. Why do you have entities without a clear identity? If these are value types then there should not be a repository for them in the first place. Figure out your key, everything else is just a "search", not a "get by id" type of call.

Comment: I disagree with the statement that "id and keys are not id's and keys"...The first case is a get by id focused on PK. It assumes the table has a single PK defined. It does not work accurately in cases where there are compound PK's for reason mentioned in earlier comment. The second case is for when there are multiple PK's defined. It does not work if you search on non PK fields. The third case is if you want to search on other fields also but return only the first item found or an exception if more than one is found. There are cases when this is needed.